# Cant use multi auth middleware with guard in route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

im using two auth table in my application

organizer and admin.

my config/auth.php file is here

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'manager'
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'manager' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'managers',
        ],
        'organizer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'organizers',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'managers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Manager::class,
        ],
        'organizers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Organizer::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [

    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

]
```

here is my problem on web.php (route)

```
Route::middleware('auth:manager')->prefix('/account')->group(function()
{
    Route::get('/desk',function()
    {
        echo 1;
    });
});
Route::middleware('auth:organizer')->prefix('/account')->group(function()
{
    Route::get('/desk',function()
    {
        echo 2;
    });
});
```

there is any problem here? because when i login into manager or organizer and set auth for theme its not working on middlware.

can someone solve my problem?

Comment: Seems like you are targeting the same url i.e. `/account/desk` with both `manager` and `organizer` guards. Shouldn't you have guard specific routes i.e. `/account/organizer/desk` and `account/manager/desk`

Comment: Depends on what are you trying to do. You can stack up middleware

Comment: thank you @alithedeveloper. my problem solved. just change /account to /organizer and /manager. i just create new prefix for each auth